# Finding checkboxes inside a gridview in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following  code:

```
<ListView Name="lvwYears"
          Margin="0,32,191,29"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=YearCollection}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumnHeader>
                    <CheckBox Click="CheckBox_Checked"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                              Content="Year"
                              Padding="50,0,0,0"
                              Margin="20,0,0,0"></CheckBox>
                </GridViewColumnHeader>
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox Click="CheckBoxIndividual_Click"
                                  Name="cbxYears"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                  Content="{Binding}"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                  Padding="50,0,0,0"
                                  Margin="20,0,0,0" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
```

I want to iterate through the checkboxes and check them whenever the CheckBox in the GridViewcolumnHeader is checked. I've tried using the VisualTree and have failed, I get errors in that the element must be Visual or Visual3D.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your checkbox is databound. So why don't you just check the data?

Comment: It's being controlled by just a list of ints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to check the checkboxes without their IsChecked being bound to something.  Change your ItemsSource to a collection of structs with your integer and a bool.  When the checkbox is checked, iterate through and set all the bools to true.

If you really insist on leaving your integer list in place, then as a total hack you could use the Loaded event in each checkbox to record it in a list and then check everything in the list when the top checkbox was checked, but I would not recommend this.

Comment: Thanks, I already had it bound to a List of objects, but had to change it due to a requirement. I'm just gonna change it back and explain why it won't work this way.

Comment: Agreed - the MVVM pattern combined with proper use of data binding makes this whole old-skool method of iterating controls redundant.